# Custom error page for code 500 not showing in flask for sqlalchemy error

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, sqlalchemy

I want to have a custom error page for internal errors. Right know i'm testing it by restarting my database service and trying to load a page before it connects again. The queries return an OperationalError

I've disabled debug mode so that i don't get the stack trace but instead of the custom 500 page I get the default text on white background.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to link a sqlalchemy error to the custom 500 page. If I don't define a event listener for sqlalchemy the flask error handler won't get called.

```
@db.event.listens_for(db.engine, "handle_error")
def handle_exception(context):
    internal_error(context.original_exception)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

Removing the sqlalchemy event or reraising the error there also doesn't work.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2019 17:29:04] "GET /products HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
...stack strace...
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown) terminating connection due to administrator command
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

*UPDATE:* Now that I thik about it. I don't think is has anything to do with sqlalchemy. I tried dividing by zero to see if I will get my custom page but the same thing happens.

Comment: you are both decorating your errorhandler with `app.errorhandler` and registering it with `app.register_error_handler`. That can't be right.

Comment: Oh yes, that was one of the things I tried in order to fix it. I edited my question. Even with one it wsill doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, now I see it, nevermind. You never have to call the Flask errorhandler explicitly. Just throw the exception up or completely remove your `handle_exception`.